# How to give RW permissions on a folder in Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I am deploying an MVC 3.0 web app to Windows Azure. I have an action method that takes a file uploaded by the user and stores it in a folder within my web app.

How could I give RW permissions to that folder to the running process? I read about start up tasks and have a basic understanding, but I wouldn't know,

1. How to give the permission itself, and
2. Which running process (user) should I give the permission to.

Many thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

In addition to @David's answer below, I found this link extremely useful:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For local storage, I wouldn't get caught up with granting access permissions to various directories. Instead, take advantage of the storage resources available specifically to your running VM's. With a given instance size, you have local storage available to you ranging from 20GB to almost 2TB (full sizing details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee814754.aspx)). To take advantage of this space, you'd create local storage resources within your project:
[image]

Then, in code, grab a drive letter to that storage:

```
var storageRoot = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("moreStorage").RootPath;
```

Now you're free to use that storage. And... none of that requires any startup tasks or granting of permissions.

Now for the caveat: This is storage that's local to each running instance, and isn't shared between instances. Further, it's *non-durable* - if the disk crashes, the data is gone.

For persistent, durable file storage, Blob Storage is a much better choice, as it's *durable* (triple-replicated within the datacenter, and geo-replicated to another datacenter) and it's external to your role instances, accessible from any instance (or any app, including your on-premises apps).

Since blob storage is organized by container, and blobs within container, it's fairly straightforward to organize your blobs (and store pretty much anything in a given blob, up to 200GB each). Also, it's trivial to upload/download files to/from blobs, either to file streams or local files (in the storage resources you allocated, as illustrated above).

Comment: Hi @David, you are the man! Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, cheers!